# What to do if accepted answer is wrong?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

What to do if an accepted answer is just plain wrong / stupid / guides others in a wrong direction?

I thought that this question should be asked somewhere before, but I cannot find it.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938498/iis-does-not-scale-but-cpu-does-not-max-out-either-why-is-it-slowing-down) I was curious about reading the answers. 
The question itself interesting, but the accepted answer is somehow disturbing,
not to say just plain wrong.

What to do in that case? Downvoting does not seems to be enough. Leaving a comment does not help either. Are thare better means?

Comment: You downvote, perhaps leave a comment, perhaps vote up another correct answer, *and move on*.

Comment: Okay, so "forget about it" is the way to go?

Comment: @Mare, maybe not so much "forget about it" as "you did all you could and there are many others like this, let's move on to more interesting things".

Comment: This is an indicator to me that "all you can do" is not enough here.

Comment: @Mare, it's understandable, but what more is there to do? If downvoting and commenting fails (the answerer does not care about their answer) and posting your own answer fails (the community does not care about the question), what to do? Locate the answerer and drive to their house with an Official SE Injunction To Correct Their Answer? *(Disclaimer: please don't do that.)*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi For example a possibility to mark an answer as incorrect would be a way to handle that. Flagging is discouraged (understandable) and comments will never be read (as is) and downvoting will not do the job (or even give someone badges)

Comment: @Mare, let's say we do that. But if you mark an answer as incorrect and no one is around to hear it (since downvoting, commenting, and answering did not work), does it make a sound?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi The short answer is: YES. Marking an answer as incorrect (given some criteria like reputation for a tag or something like that) should in turn make the answer be removed (or at least not open for accept, I strongly believe). An already "accepted" answer shall be "unaccepted" if there are strong evidence that it simply is wrong. In the case that I gave as an example the answer is just "I did not manage to do that", which has no value for the community and on the other hand suggests to future readers that it is not possible. There should be a voting system like that for questions

Comment: Ah, that's another feature request entirely. One that has been asked many times before, and shot down every time I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that I am drifting right now.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But in my case here, the accepted answer has gone! So it got as much attention as it deserved I believe :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do one or more of the following:

- Down-vote it and optionally leave a comment explaining why it's wrong.
- Provide the correct answer, or up-vote one of the existing correct answers.
- If the answer is only wrong in detail - edit it so that it is correct.
- Leave a comment on the question so that the OP will see it and rethink the acceptance. If you do decide to do this, take care to word your comment carefully so it doesn't come across as badly.

What you should not do:

- Flag the answer for moderator attention. We have enough to do and are not here to deal with wrong answers.

Comment: I can sense in your last sentence you've been knee-deep in flags for a while :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "knee-deep" and "for a while" don't even come close.

Comment: Uhm... This is a question answering website. You run the website, as a mod, and you say it's not important to you that answers are correct?... Maybe i need to get off this website if that's really how the mods feel. It's a huge problem when theres an answer with 100+ upvotes that is patently wrong, because thousands of people may see it and then be misled, perhaps believing the wrong answer and arguing it as true in the future. It spreads misinformation. This is a Q/A site for technical information. Correct answers really, really matter. There needs to be a way to correct.

Comment: `If the answer is only wrong in detail - edit it so that it is correct.` What is an answer that is correct but is "wrong in detail"?

Comment: But what if you find the question (07/2017) being upvoted 308 times, the accepted answer (07/2017) being upvoted 483 times, and the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58885970/11154841) (11/2019) being upvoted just 30 times? The down-vote will not outbalance the fast search engine voters. See [Would a new question on how to update Anaconda be in line with the community if there is already a similar but messy and old 500k views question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411294/would-a-new-question-on-how-to-update-anaconda-be-in-line-with-the-community-if).