# Is it okay to advise people not to vote on a certain answer to your question?

Tags: discussion, voting

I recently stumbled across [a question about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909025/how-to-set-default-java-platform-in-netbeans-8-2) some setting in NetBeans.

The original poster of the question had edited ([revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40909025/3)) their post with the following:

> PLEASE DO NOT UPVOTE LenglBoy ANSWER AS IT WAS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS NOT LOOKING FOR

Is it okay to explicitly give this kind of advice?

---

Related:

- [Is it okay to ask for upvotes in a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323847/is-it-okay-to-ask-for-upvotes-in-a-question)

Comment: No, you can't tell people *how* to use *their* votes.

Comment: For reference, I have rolled back that edit in the post now (as @JeanneDark says, it's fluff or noise, so doesn't belong there), but the revision can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40909025/3).

Comment: The other problem with the text is it just rude, in my opinion, @MCEmperor . The OP is SHOUTING at some one, which is just uncalled for. I also find it very odd that they (the OP) came back about **2 years** later to add that edit.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, regardless of whether the advice itself would be appropriate or not – I had problems with the wording of this advice as well, because I found it a little rude.

Comment: "Oh okay, it is exactly what I am looking for but because it did not help you I will not upvote it then". NO! The entire premise of the demand is ludicrous, the product of a person who completely misses the point of the site.

Comment: I frequently see people commenting below answers that this was not what they were looking for (without any voting recommendation and all caps letters though). It's okay, especially if accompanied with additional arguments why it's not what they were looking for. Potentially it hints how the question could be improved (in case it was a bit unclear).

Comment: The advise is quite indelicate because the question is self-answered (and eventually accepted)

Comment: Now the answer got meta-effected and 6 new upvotes have appeared. I wonder how many of those voters actually tried it. Seems like most voters don't actually check whether an answer works, and with people coming from meta, I would expect the rates to be even worse.

Comment: That answer really *is* just some guy telling the questioner an approach the questioner already knew about and linked to, which the questioner says doesn't work. The answerer's claims about the effects in the comments suggest they changed from 1.7 to 1.8, which is the exact opposite of what the questioner is trying to do.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the OP did leave a [comment explaining the problem with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909025/how-can-i-set-the-default-java-platform-in-netbeans-8-2#comment69032664_40910055) at the time it was posted. I can’t even guess at what prompted the edit to the question; I don’t see anything in the timelines that would hint at it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica *"suggest they changed from 1.7 to 1.8, which is the exact opposite of what the questioner is trying"* - That's totally irrelevant, the question is only asking how to override the default version, no more. *"That answer really is just some guy telling the questioner an approach the questioner already knew about and linked to, which the questioner says doesn't work."* - Also irrelevant, we're not here to help OP, we're here to help everyone, the solution clearly _did_ work for the answerer even if not for OP (although I won't defend the answerer not flagging as dupe)

Comment: @Nick: The question explicitly is about switching to 1.7. It would have been better if they included that in the title, but it's still in the body, and not all question details need to be in the title to be part of the question.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's just an example of what they're doing, the fact they're the exact version numbers is not at all relevant to the question, all the path does is point to the JDK

Comment: @Nick: No, it's not just an example. It's crucial to the question, because (according to the questioner, and it seems likely that they're correct, judging by resources I've found on what the `netbeans_jdkhome` setting does) changing the `netbeans_jdkhome` setting to a 1.7 JDK makes Netbeans fail on startup. The question is about finding something that works for Java 1.7.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica If that's the case then OP is literally asking "Why can't I run this Java 1.8 software on Java 1.7", clearly I expected more of them.

Comment: @Nick: No they're not. They are asking how to make Java *projects* they're working on run in 1.7. Netbeans can do that, even when Netbeans itself is running on 1.8, but it looks like this has to be configured on a per-project level. There doesn't seem to be a way to set 1.7 as the default.

Comment: @user2357112 Then why does the answer by their *"Prior versions allowed me to do that."* link to a question about the version _NetBeans_ runs on, _not_ its projects, and why do [this](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781785282645/1/ch01lvl1sec13/netbeans-configuration) and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/working_nbeans.htm#NBDAG162) give no indication that `netbeans_jdkhome` does (or has ever done) that? Clearly they have always misunderstood what the setting they've been configuring is and just had it work by dumb luck.

Comment: @Nick: Netbeans uses the JDK it's running on as the default JDK for new projects, so changing `netbeans_jdkhome` changes both Netbeans's own JDK and the new project JDK. See [6.8 Setting the Target JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/netbeans/nb82/netbeans/NBDAG/create_japps.htm#NBDAG465).

Comment: @Nick A bit off topic here, but you have been unfairly criticizing the technical expertise of the OP of the linked question. Their question arose because NetBeans release 8.x was built using JDK 8, and needed JRE 8 to run, but NetBeans 8.x also had to provide support for Java 7 projects, since JDK 7 was still widely used. But because Java is not backward compatible, you can't use JDK 7 to run NetBeans 8. AFAIK, the issue raised is specific to NetBeans 8.x only. Earlier and later releases could afford to be more selective on which JDKs they had to  support, and don't face the problem.

Comment: There was a recent [last few days] meta post [I forget where/which] about changing the SO answer ranking so that if the upvotes on a given answer exceed the upvotes on the accepted answer, the most upvoted answer will appear _above_ the accepted answer. I wasn't sure I liked that and this [if true] appears to bare out that the accepted answer should be ranked first, regardless of the number of upvotes of the other answers. IMO, shouldn't the questioner have the final say on which is the best answer [based on accepting it] over others that might come [years] later?

Comment: @Larnu Don't see any reason why you *can't* (in a comment), especially if there's some explanation why, but no one is obligated t follow the recommendation.

Comment: @CraigEstey that's a discussion many sites on the network have right now. It might make sense on smaller sites where curators and mods can handhold most, if not every question. With the scale of SO, giving OPs an ability to unilaterally decide what is "the best" answer (and as stats show, accepting an answer tends to lead to biased voting) is... problematic. Overall, there is nothing wrong with giving a clear indication that an answer is the one that helped the OP the most, but pinning it unnecessarily favors what might be outdated, bad practice, etc. And as data shows too, folks *do* [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] tend to copy from the top answer without thinking too much. But all that will probably make for a better discussion on the "outdated answers" project announcement :)

Comment: @jpmc26 there is a *big* difference with saying why *you* voted the way you did and telling people to not upvote something. The former is fine (though for downvotes be prepared for backlash by less mature users), the latter is not; again, I can and will use my votes how I want to, not how someone else tells me to.

Comment: @Larnu No, there isn't. The only reason you would explain your reason for voting the way you did is to try to influence others to do the same. The only difference is how explicit or subtle you're being.

Comment: Yes there is, @jpmc26 . There is a Huge difference with "Careful, this answer is dangerous as it suffers from the {insert name here} vulnerability." and "Don't upvote this! In fact, you should downvote it. It's Dangerous as it has security vulnerabilities!" One warns people about the problem, but they are still free to chose how they want to vote, the other tells them they must downvote it. The user themselves who is voting , and only them, should be choosing how to vote. They can use the comments to make a more informed decision, but they should not be told what to do.

Comment: If you disagree with my comments, then @jpmc26, then please downvote this question, and the answer from JeanneDark. If you agree with them, please use your votes how you wish.

Comment: @Larnu The difference is one of them gives more explanation for your consideration. They both encourage you to downvote. One of them just does it implicitly rather than explicitly. Consider the combination: "Don't upvote this! In fact, you should downvote it. This answer is dangerous as it suffers from the {insert name here} vulnerability!" There's nothing wrong with that comment, and it should be upvoted (assuming it's correct) for the substantive explanation and for recommending a course of action that will improve our site content's quality.

Comment: *"There's nothing wrong with that comment"* Yes, there is... It tells you how to vote... Anyway, as you disagree, then please do as I stated and downvote the answer and question (as by your own words, it's ok for me to tell you what to do with your votes).

Comment: @Larnu Why are you telling me how to vote if telling people how to vote is wrong? Also, why are you telling me to downvote the question when it asserts no particular opinion?

Comment: Because you *think* it's ok, @jpmc26 ... Clearly if you don't like me telling you how to vote, you don't actually feel the same way as your comments say you do... Which just evidences my actual point. Plus, both the question and answer are also against being told how to vote, and so by definition you should be voting against them (like I told you to).

Comment: @Larnu If I thought there was something wrong with it, I'd flag your comment. Obviously, I'm not doing that. I *don't* care if you tell me how to vote. I care that you're being intentionally inconsistent with your own made up rules that are nonsensical to begin with, and I care that you're giving bad advice. Actually, you're intentionally trying to be provocative rather than defend your position, and *that* actually is a problem (likely a minor CoC violation).

Comment: I've not given any bad advice. In fact, the point/advice t I gave is *still* the most upvoted [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411963/is-it-okay-to-advise-people-not-to-vote-on-a-certain-answer-to-your-question?noredirect=1#comment870897_411963) @jpmc26 . You're not going to listen to my point, no matter how much i try to drive it home, so this conversation is over.

Comment: @Larnu Pot calling the kettle black. I explicitly called out your bad advice: "Also, why are you telling me to downvote the question when it asserts no particular opinion?" I change my mind all the time when I'm given a good reason to. You haven't given a good reason, much less a reasoned response to the points I've raised. You've literally just asserted your opinion without providing any justification for it.

Comment: My favourite reference for when people are too focused on votes and on how to vote: [_"Votes are like flatulence; everyone does it, but you really don't need to call attention to it. If we're gonna talk about something, it should be the content of the post, not how folks voted on it."_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312634)

Comment: I don't mind the idea, although the way it was expressed in your sample is objectionable. But it has to be remembered that, by definition, the person posting the question doesn't know the answer, and may not recognize it even when it has been provided. This is rather common.

Comment: @user207421 Even if it is _"rather common"_ that OPs don't recognize the answer even when it has been provided, that is definitely not true in this specific case. Not only was the answer that the OP was (obnoxiously) objecting to incorrect, but it was obvious that the person posting the answer didn't even understand the problem. I'm not condoning that OP's conduct at all, but I certainly understand their frustration at seeing the clueless answer being upvoted.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, it's [fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/11682469) that doesn't belong in a post. Feel free to remove it.

Questions and answers are also not just for the OP. Stack Overflow is not a free help desk but wants to become a [library of programming knowledge](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for many people.

The OP can mark the answer that helped them most by accepting it, but others can vote as they wish (the tooltip provides guidance) and whether an answer was useful to the OP or not may not be relevant for other users at all. If another answer was useful to you, feel free to upvote it, even if it was not the OP's main choice (for sure, I'm just referring to answers that meet our quality standards).

The accepted answer may be [wrong](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266962/11682469), bad practice, not well-explained, overly specific (eg. code-only), outdated (eg. see [Outdated Answers: accepted answer is now unpinned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411352/11682469)), etc.

Comment: I'm not understanding why you are putting any emphasis on accepted answers here (_"The accepted answer may be..."_). In this specific case the accepted answer was posted by the OP, and was correct. The issue that frustrated the OP was that a completely incorrect answer that ignored the question and the OP's comments was upvoted. That OP must have their hair on fire right now because the meta effect has caused the wrong and bad answer to be upvoted even more! The final paragraph of your answer is fine in principle, but applies to all answers, and not just the accepted one.

Comment: @skomisa Given that sentence follows a paragraph specifically discussing the accepted answer, it feels like it's elaborating on that point, rather than making a general point about answers.

Comment: @M.Justin Well we will have to agree to disagree, because I don't think the preceding paragraph was _"specifically discussing the accepted answer"_ at all. On the contrary, it was making the point that others are free to upvote _any_ answer regardless of the OP's views or accepted answer. Therefore it makes more sense that the comments in the final paragraph should apply to all answers rather than just the accepted answer.

Comment: @skomisa The preceding paragraph mentioned that the OP was free to accept any answer -- not just the top-voted one -- and the last paragraph simply elaborates on why it's important to keep "accept" and "votes" different and have votes be independent of the OP's opinion of what the most useful answer is.

Comment: @skomisa Answers and questions don't 'belong' to the original asker. All questions (and answers) are but Shadows of True Platonic Questions and different people may derive different utility (or other value) from the same answers or the same question.

Answer (score 25):

No, this is thoroughly in bad taste. If the OP wants to post "I'm afraid this isn't what I was looking for, please read my question more carefully" as a comment on an answer, that's fine. If that deters people from upvoting that answer, also fine. Telling people how to vote is never okay. Editing the question to contain complaints, natter, or anything else that isn't really the question: also not okay.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to never tell people how to vote.  For instance, we should tell them not to [serial upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me), engage in voting fraud, use the voting system for purposes other than it's intended, etc.

Comment: eh, every rule has exceptions if you poke at it enough.

Comment: @KevinB even the rule you just stated? :P

Comment: Rule 184: This rule has no exceptions

Comment: @M.Justin ordinary users can't see if someone is doing any of those things, which makes "reminding" them not to basically an accusation.

Answer (score 16):

No, it's not ok.

If the question asker wants to inform others that an answer is not what they were looking for, they can downvote such answer. When you encounter such information being added to the main post, please roll back/edit it out.

We can't tell other users how to vote. We should not encourage voting on any given post, whether it's up or down. You may encourage people to use their voting privileges when it's appropriate, but don't tell them which posts to vote on.

Comment: "Furthermore, we can't tell other users how to vote. We should not encourage voting either way on any given post." Do you realize how much content on Meta would have to be deleted if that were correct?

Comment: @jpmc26 Content on Meta may not always align with other content on Meta, for multiple reasons. And regardless, that isn't a reason to delete that content.

Answer (score 9):

For your specific example, it had the following problems (rev 3):

- It appended an "all caps" message to the question, which on the Internet is considered shouting and borderline rude in some cases. It is *very* distracting from the rest of the question, so it sorts as what SO refers to as "fluff".
- It adds nothing to the question itself.
- Promoting/anti-promoting certain answers from the question itself is very poor style. The person asking a question is supposed to promote an answer by accepting it and up-voting it. And optionally down-vote unhelpful or incorrect answers, ideally leaving a comment about why it is wrong or unhelpful.

This harmful edit was correctly removed with a rollback (rev 4).

---

In general, it might be acceptable to promote other answers from another ("competing")  *answer*. I often do this when I just want to append something to an otherwise good answer, or leave some information related to the question, which in itself isn't a complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of comments and answers here claiming that telling people how to vote is somehow wrong or unacceptable. That position is absurd. The problem is not *whether* you try to influence people's votes, but *how*.

Consider the following comment:

> This answer suffers from SQL injection vulnerabilities because it constructs the query using string concatenation rather than parameterizing the inputs. This is a *terrible* practice that should *never* show up in production code.

Now consider this comment:

> This answer suffers from SQL injection vulnerabilities because it constructs the query using string concatenation rather than parameterizing the inputs. This is a *terrible* practice that should *never* show up in production code; this answer deserves to be downvoted.

Is there really any difference between these two comments? No, there really is not. They are both encouraging you to downvote the post and avoid its advice by pointing out a severe problem, and they are both encouraging you to use our site's mechanic for rating content appropriately. One of them just does so implicitly while the other makes the action you should take explicit. That is *fine.* There is nothing wrong with providing a substantive response and encouraging people to take an appropriate action in light of that information.

So what is and is not an appropriate way of influencing other people's votes? It's pretty simple.

1. Make sure your response is more than just telling people to vote. Provide a substantive *reason* for why they should vote a particular way.
2. Make sure you provide it in the correct location. On the main site, it does not ever belong in a question or answer post (even an answer that explicitly addresses major problems in a competing answer). On Meta, it only belongs in a post that is intended to provide specific guidance about expected behavior; such posts should usually include specific policy or analysis that will allow users to generalize the behavior to many posts. A comment responding to a particular post is also a place this belongs, assuming you can fit the explanation in the comment with it.
3. Provide quality content. Just because you have decided that you need to provide some information to influence people's votes doesn't mean your content gets to be low quality. All of our quality expectations still apply. On top of the correctness of the substance, this means it should use good formatting, punctuation, grammar, and word choice. This also means you shouldn't let a tangent about voting prevent you from improving your own question or answer. If an answer is unhelpful, consider whether the question can be clarified or otherwise improved to explain why that approach doesn't work, or whether it would be appropriate to address the problems of the other approach in your competing answer. This may be useful information even if a bad answer is eventually deleted.
4. Save explicit voting recommendations for extreme cases. If you go around telling people how to vote on every post you see or decide to comment on, it's annoying. Save it for common but catastrophic errors where the author really should know better but many do not (like SQL injections) or for solutions that are absolutely brilliant but weren't obvious. Most of the time, it's enough to just point out the negative or positive qualities of a post directly, and voting doesn't need to be mentioned.
5. Don't be rude. There's a difference between being *harsh* and rude. Some circumstances warrant being a little harsh, but don't cross the line. (Yes, what constitutes "rude" is subjective and a matter of debate that I won't get into, but for the moment, let's just agree there *is* some line you shouldn't cross.)

---

How does your specific example stack up against that?

- It's almost all caps. Very poor style.
- It's in the question, rather than a comment on the answer.
- It doesn't provide a substantive reason. (The user *does* provide substantive objections in direct comments on the answer, but not in the content you quoted.)

So yes, the specific content you quoted needs to go. But not because it tells people how to vote. It's because of the bad substance, style, and location.

Comment: In this case, it would be ok for the question to say something like "setting `netbeans_jdkhome=` in the .conf doesn't help because $reasons".  Even if that's done as an edit in response to an answer (which is maybe answering a different question, or just a wrong guess or misinterpretation of the problem).  It's best for the question not to even mention that an answer suggested that (so deleting the answer wouldn't invalidate part of the question), just say what the non-viable solution was in a non-complainy way like you would if it was something you'd thought of and ruled out before asking.

Comment: So the distinction I'm making is that I agree with you that a comment under an answer pointing out something is dangerous and needs to be downvoted is fine. And agreed that voting discussion shouldn't ever appear in the question. But technical discussion in the question *can* if necessary be placed in a way that lets readers connect the dots and vote *if* they actually look at what the question and answer are saying. That's what stops the question from being a bully pulpit against answers that don't solve the question the way the querent wanted, for reasons that weren't stated in the question.

Comment: @PeterCordes Right. This doesn't preclude clarifying the question in response to an unhelpful answer. Any improvements to the *substance* of a post are always welcome, irrespective of the situation with voting and other posts.

Answer (score -41):

It is perfectly tok to advice users that the answer is wrong

This isn't an outdated answer as it didn't work at the time and **now** it works.

I also don't see why the comment was deleted as it doesn't is against the rules

As always here truth and divergent meanings get bashed.

Why must q comment that tells TT bat a answer is crap be deleted.
There is no cause. The post and comm not are five years old and a lot of water got down then drain. So what does it care if five years that does go. The answer has the highest count and would be tested.

Comment: If one want to comment on a post, one can do so by posting a an actual comment on the post. But even then, advising (or even just commenting) on voting is simply inappropriate. The paragraph was deleted because it was noise, and we remove noise from posts. Not because it was "against the rules".

Comment: If the OP wanted to state that the answer that they referenced wasn't helpful, they should have posted a comment that stated it; perhaps something like *"This answer references the link that I included in my question, but doesn't provide an alternative solution, which is what I am looking for. As such it doesn't answer my question."* If the OP wanted, they could also/instead downvote said answer as "not useful". Editing their question with such noise to SHOUT at the user who posted the answer is far from appropriate.

Comment: "It is perfectly OK to advise users that the answer is wrong." - yes, but NOT in the post! Warnings about accuracy should be reflected by votes and comments, and your answer here is a perfect example of what should happen. It would not be appropriate to add "PLEASE DO NOT UPVOTE nbk's ANSWER AS IT WAS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS NOT LOOKING FOR" to the question, or even for OP to edit it into your answer, but it's perfectly fine for your answer to receive downvotes and comments pointing out what parts you're wrong about

Comment: Also, I just realized that this answer reeks of not reading into the situation; it was never a comment, [it was a revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40909025/3)

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has a delete vote on it. It's a valid answer, and is relevant to the question. Agreement/disagreement with the answer can be expressed through up/down votes and/or comments, not by deleting it.

Comment: Indeed, wrong as it is, there seems to be no need to delete it.

Comment: @yivi Advising people on voting in a comment is "inappropriate"? That's utterly ridiculous. We give voting advice all the time on Meta.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Any attempt to influence a person's voting pattern is an "encouragement" to vote a particular way. That includes even explaining your own reasons for voting a particular way or specifying problems or good qualities of a post. There is *nothing* wrong with trying to influence other people's voting patterns, either here or on the main site. Mods should not be categorically deleting any content merely on that basis, only on the basis of how much substance the post or comment contains and whether it's in the appropriate place or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It is *absurd* to suggest that the activity of influencing other people's votes is unacceptable. We would not be allowed to discuss anyone else's posts *at all* if that were the case.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin What a useless distinction. There is no real difference between saying it outright and doing it without saying you are. You're still doing it either way. In fact, it's *more* respectful to be forthright about your intentions rather than conceal them or be deceptive. "This is because the reasons users voted a certain way may be different." So what? People disagree. That doesn't mean they shouldn't advocate for their opinion or try to change other people's minds. Changing and developing people's thoughts by sharing information is the *entire point* of both SO and its Meta!

Comment: @SylvesterKruin In fact, you're trying to change my mind right now! And if you succeeded, it would change my voting on this question's answers! So you're trying to influence my voting. It would change nothing if you outright stated you were trying to.

Comment: The site itself encourages/discourages voting, why can't it's users.